# Why does request.get() return empty string?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I am new to python and google app-engine. I made the simple code to get input from a form and then display it on a new page . However, the self.request.get() methods returned empty strings. Why is this happening and how do I solve this problem?

```
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2


template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)


class NewPost(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(jinja_env.get_template('newpost.html').render())

    def post(self):
        title = self.request.get('title')
        body = self.request.get('body')


        self.redirect('/message') 

class Message(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):    
        title = self.request.get('title')
        body =  self.request.get('body')

        self.response.out.write('message: ' + title + body)



app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([webapp2.Route(r'/', handler=NewPost, name='newpost'), webapp2.Route(r'/message', handler=Message, name='message')], debug = True)
```

the newpost.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title> Title </title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">
    <label>
        <div>Title</div>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{title}}">


    <label>
        <div>Body</div>
    </label>
    <textarea name="body">{{body}}</textarea>


    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a side-note, you should `try/except` inside every `get` method and every `post` method.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I used datastore and solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The form parameters are available to the `POST /` request (`NewPost.post()`), but they are not carried forward on the redirect to `/message`.  You have to store the form data somehow (such as to the datastore) when handling the `POST`, then retrieve it from storage after the redirect.